# What makes show errors with red squiggly underline in Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: typescript

I was learning Typescript and installed tsc compiler. So, as I was writing code, red squiggly line appeared for error code. The question is what ensures behind the scenes that red squiggly line is shown? Is it true that IDE allows tsc compiler analyze constantly our code? Pls guys if something is not clear, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it true that IDE allows tsc compiler analyze constantly our code?

The IDE doesn't call tsc for that. As the [architecture diagram](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview) shows, tsc live above the core compiler, part of which

> Type resolver/ Checker: Resolving types of each construct, checking semantic operations and generate diagnostics as appropriate.
>
> TypeChecker is the core of the TypeScript type system. It is the part responsible for figuring out relationships between Symbols from different files, assigning Types to Symbols, and generating any semantic **Diagnostics (i.e. errors)**

Note that

> The TypeChecker computes everything lazily; it only "resolves" the necessary information to answer a question. The checker will only examine Nodes/Symbols/Types that contribute to the question at hand and will not attempt to examine additional entities.

and since you're using IDE, the

> Language Service: The "Language Service" exposes an additional layer around the core compiler pipeline that are best suiting **editor-like applications**. The language service supports the common set of a typical editor operations like statement completions, signature help, code formatting and outlining, colorization, etc... Basic re-factoring like rename, Debugging interface helpers like validating breakpoints as well as TypeScript-specific features like support of incremental compilation (--watch equivalent on the command-line). The language service is **designed to efficiently handle scenarios with files changing over time within a long-lived compilation context**; in that sense, the language service provides a slightly different perspective about working with programs and source files from that of the other compiler interfaces.

So behind the screen, every little change to your ts file will be immediately analyzed, and with the lazy resolver and optimized service, it's possible to give you real-time error diagnostic and the intellisense.